# Getting "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated" when using UPPER in Snowflake IN Subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, common-table-expression, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, in-subquery

I have a Snowflake table as following:

```
create table field_names_to_retrieve("QualifiedApiName" varchar(80));
INSERT INTO field_names_to_retrieve VALUES ('reason');
INSERT INTO field_names_to_retrieve VALUES ('reason__c');
INSERT INTO field_names_to_retrieve VALUES ('name__c'); 
INSERT INTO field_names_to_retrieve VALUES ('email__c');
```

If I run the following query, it works:

```
SELECT
    "QualifiedApiName",
    CASE WHEN UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE("QualifiedApiName", '__c$', '')) NOT IN 
            (SELECT "QualifiedApiName" FROM "field_names_to_retrieve")
        THEN REGEXP_REPLACE("QualifiedApiName", '__c$', '')
    ELSE "QualifiedApiName"
END
FROM
"field_names_to_retrieve";
```

However the following query does NOT work. Notice that there in UPPER in the subquery:

```
SELECT
    "QualifiedApiName",
    CASE WHEN UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE("QualifiedApiName", '__c$', '')) NOT IN 
            (SELECT UPPER("QualifiedApiName") FROM "field_names_to_retrieve")
        THEN REGEXP_REPLACE("QualifiedApiName", '__c$', '')
    ELSE "QualifiedApiName"
END
FROM
"field_names_to_retrieve";
```

Any ideas on why the subquery with UPPER fails?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the expression is an issue with `NOT IN`.  I discourage using `NOT IN` with subqueries anyway because `NULL` values are not handled intuitively.

Does it work with `NOT EXISTS`?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM "field_names_to_retrieve" fntr2
                              WHERE UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(fntr."QualifiedApiName", '__c$', '')) = UPPER(fntr2."QualifiedApiName")
                             )
            THEN REGEXP_REPLACE("QualifiedApiName", '__c$', '')
            ELSE "QualifiedApiName"
        END)
FROM "field_names_to_retrieve" fntr;
```